# Book about an immortal diplomat who wipes out an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, books

Searching for the title of a book about an immortal diplomat who marries an immortal princess, who also has the power to wipe out an alien invasion using his mind?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)